# Custom Web Part Properties in SharePoint 2010 Visual Web Parts-Dynamic Dropdown

Tags: visual-web-part, custom-web-part-property

I want to have a custom webpart property with a dynamic dropdownlist (data coming from sharepoint list).

I was able to make a static dropdownlist as mentioned [here](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.in/2011/04/custom-properties-in-sharepoint-2010_7158.html).

Can anyone help me how to make a dynamic dropdownlist?Code samples would be useful. Please help.

Comment: [The question is answered on msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/796fcfc6-fe17-4192-9b26-47d56d172d4e)